# Not able to run terraform from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I am trying to run a terraform command from jenkins pipeline but I am getting an error stating that, "terraform command not found". I have installed terraform plugins as well as in the system where jenkins is also installed. Please help.

Comment: this question would probably be more appropriate for stackoverflow or devops, see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13805/should-we-do-something-about-the-high-number-of-jenkins-questions-with-no-votes

Comment: ok I will do that